# Can Invisible Dog Fence Wire be run in same Conduit with Cat6 for POE Cameras without Interference?

Tags: electrical, security, data-wiring

I am pulling 300' runs of Cat5 or Cat6 for POE security cameras.  In the same ditch will be a 2" conduit with fiber runs for high-speed internet service.  My client wants to add an invisible dog fence to the conduits.

It seems problematic to me.  Don't dog fences emit a fairly strong magnetic field?  And would that interfere with the POE power and signal transmission to the cameras (and possibly other sensors)?

Comment: Just use S/FTP cable.

Comment: Make sure you think about voltage drop on that POE.  Low voltage + thin wire is a perfect storm for critical voltage drop.   And you're absolutely right, dog fences are antennas. You need to install them according to the instructions if you want them to work.   I'm not worried about cross talk, submarine ELF transmissions don't interfere with FM radio.

Comment: Occurs to me (belatedly) that properly buried conduits (typically 18" of cover for communications, barring dropping a mint on rigid, which would definitely make the dog fence not work) are likely too deep for properly functioning invisible fence wires, which need to be closer to the surface.

Answer (score 1):

Most information I can find states that this type of product operates in the 7-10 Khz range.

As such, while I would certainly consider it preferable on general principles to separate it from the network wiring, I'd also consider it low-likelihood of causing notable interference with DC (POE) or 100 MHz (network) signals on twisted pairs doing differential encoding (which is what "Base-T" ethernet does.)

The twists cause any coupled signal to "self-cancel" as each twisted section opposes the signal picked up in the next turn of the twist, and the differential encoding means that only the difference in voltage on each pair is observed for network signaling. The fiber, of course, is completely immune.

On the third hand - "client" - Probably simpler to just tell them "no" than to buy into any (even remotely) possible problems this might cause. But depending on the client, and the budget, might be worth a practical test bundling 300 feet of dog fence wire with a couple of Cat6 (not in a trench for the test) and looking for any differences in signal behavior with the dog fence wire dead or active. At their cost for your time, not "for free."